# How does the tensorflow session.run() method knows the name of the placeholder variables?

Tags: python, tensorflow

From the tensorflow tutorial section https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/low_level_intro#feeding
the following code creates the placeholders and assign it to variables 'x' and 'y' and is passed to the run method.

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
z = x + y

print(sess.run(z, feed_dict={x: 3, y: 4.5}))
```

How does the sess.run() method know the name of the variables 'x' and 'y'. ie. How does the run method know the keys of the feed_dict argument. Is there a mechanism in the python to figure out the name of the variables ?

Comment: In `feed_dict={x: 3, y: 4.5}`, `x` and `y` are not string. They are `tf.placeholder` objects.

Comment: You can see some info about x with: `print(x.__dict__)`

Comment: @Sraw Thanks. keys can be objects, thats what i did not knew. Post your comment as the answer to accept.

Answer (score 2):

Most of objects in tensorflow can be found with a string.

When you invoke `tf.placeholder(tf.float32)`, tensorflow will do the following:

- create a node with the `Placeholder` op
- add this node to default graph
- return the node output tensor

You can set a name for any node, say `tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='myplaceholder')`, if you don't specify a node name, tensorflow will generate one, you can use `print x.op` to see the name of the op.

A tensor is named with the node name plus the output index, for example

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
print x
```

you will see something like `Placeholder:0`, which is the tensor name.

So, in you code, tensorflow can first get tensor name from `x`, and iterate the default graph to find proper node.

You can also use string for feed_dict, `{"Placeholder:0": 3}`